# Setting a standard value to a field

Tags: 8

I've created a field with drupal console. That made the following standard folder structure.

```
FieldFormatter
FieldType
Fieldwidget
```

These all have their respected php classes.

Now this field is in a content type that always is used in a Book. 
I want to this Books name into that field. 
I know how to retrieve this name trough code but i don't know how to get this value into this field in all new instances of this content type.

I thought i just needed to use a default value but that doesn't seem to work because even though i added 'default' to the schema with that value it doesn't show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a default value is configured in the field configuration. Either static in `default_value` or dynamic in `default_value_callback` pointing to a callback function which returns the default value.

For your original question, how to do this in one of the field plugins, see [No way for a field to dynamically set default value](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1797100) and especially [#6](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1797100#comment-11792569):

> I resorted to creating widgets (extending the base widgets), whose
>   only concern is to set the default value dynamically according to
>   contextual values, e.g. I have a widget that presets a default value
>   to an entity name referenced by the logged in user, something like
>   this:

```
/**
 * Define the {@link AcmeWidget} class.
 *
 * @FieldWidget(
 *   id = "acme_widget",
 *   label = @Translation("Acme Textfield"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "string"
 *   }
 * )
 *
 * @package Drupal\acme\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget
 */
class AcmeWidget extends StringTextfieldWidget {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    // Call our parent but set the value using our default value function.
    $element = parent::formElement($items, $delta, $element, $form, $form_state);

    // Get the current user organization's name.
    $user = User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
    $organization = $user->get('field_organization')->entity->title->value;

    // Set the default value if a value hasn't been set.
    $element['value']['#default_value'] = $organization;

    return $element;
  }


}
```